# How to search for specific words in list from input

Tags: python

I have to create a program that allows the user to input a type of food in a sentence, e.g. I would like pizza  or I want to order indian food. Then the sentence has to be split and then the program can search for each individual word in the text file and if it finds the word in the text file it should print out the food.

```
    TypeFood = input("What food would you like to order?")
    words = TypeFood.split()
    with open("HungryHorseMenu.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
                if words in line:
                    splitted_line = line.split(',')
                    print(splitted_line[0])
```

I get an error with this code as it says:
in ' requires string as left operand, not list

My text file is this:

> Vegetarian pizza, italian
>
> Margarita pizza, italian
>
> Meat feast pizza, italian
>
> Spaghetti bolognese, pasta, italian
>
> Tagliatteli, pasta, italian
>
> Cheeseburger, american
>
> Chicken burger, american
>
> Veggie burger, american
>
> Hot dog, american
>
> Chicken curry, indian
>
> Vegetable curry, indian

Comment: words is a list. You are doing TypeFood.split(), if you are entering only one food item you don't need to do it.

Comment: But what if they type a sentence?

Comment: Btw it seems you have an issue with padding in your code(inside for loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work, you should also consider punctuation and case sensitive, thats why I used regex.

```
import re
TypeFood = input("What food would you like to order?")
words = TypeFood.split()
with open("HungryHorseMenu.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if any(word.lower() in re.findall('\w+', line.lower()) for word in words)
            splitted_line = line.split(',')
            print(splitted_line[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if any(word in line for word in words)
```

words is a list, you have to iterate over it to check if any of the word is present in line.

Comment: This code when I type "I would like pizza" prints out everything that has letter i in it

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is that you try to search for list in string here:

```
for words in line
```

Two ways you have now:
a) the way suggested by @Sagar(I changed all to lower case and added list generator construction)

```
if any((word.lower() in line.lower() for word in words))
```

b) Check that all words are in the line(but line can also contain other words)
if all((word.lower() in line.lower() for word in words))